# Rxjava: How to combine multiple observables without all observables completing?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got multiple hot observables which may or may not emit items. As a result, I want to combine the observables and then handle the result if any of them emits a result, but if the other observables emits at item, they should be handled together.

eg.

```
observable1 = PublishSubject<>()  
observable2 = PublishSubject<>()

observable1.onNext(1)  
observable1.onNext(2)  
observable2.onNext("Test")  
observable1.onNext(3)
```

Should emit:

```
(1, null) 
(2, null)
(2, "Test")
(3, "Test")
```

It's also possible that `observable2` gets emitted before `observable1`

[`CombineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) is the closest to what I need but that only emits a result when all the observables emit at least one item. Is there a reactive operator for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `startWith` with each source to provide an initial value, or use `BehaviorSubject` with an initial value, then apply `combineLatest` on these augmented Observables. However, `null` is not allowed in RxJava 2 so you have to find a neutral value in your observable element type.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> observable1 = PublishSubject.create()  
PublishSubject<String>  observable2 = PublishSubject.create()

Observable.combineLates(
    observable1.startWith(-100000),
    observable2.startWith(""),
    (a, b) -> a + b
)
.subscribe(System.out::println)
;

observable1.onNext(1)  
observable1.onNext(2)  
observable2.onNext("Test")  
observable1.onNext(3)
```

or

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> observable1 = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(-10000)  
BehaviorSubject<String>  observable2 = BehaviorSubject.createDefault("")

Observable.combineLates(
    observable1,
    observable2,
    (a, b) -> a + b
)
.subscribe(System.out::println)
;

observable1.onNext(1)  
observable1.onNext(2)  
observable2.onNext("Test")  
observable1.onNext(3)
```